# How to make this weird string explode in PHP?

Tags: php, regex, grep

I have a string like the following

```
DAS-1111[DR-Helpfull-R]-RUN--[121668688374]-N-[+helpfull_+string]
```

The above string is a kind of formatted in groups that looks like the following:

```
A-B[C]-D-E-[F]-G-[H]
```

The think is that I like to process some of those groups, and I like to make something like explode.

I say like, because I have try this code:

```
$string = 'DAS-1111[DR-Helpfull-R]-RUN--[121668688374]-N-[+helpfull_+string]';
$parts = explode( '-', $string );
print_r( $parts );
```

and I get the following result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => DAS
    [1] => 1111[DR
    [2] => Helpfull
    [3] => R]
    [4] => RUN
    [5] => 
    [6] => [121668688374]
    [7] => N
    [8] => [+helpfull_+string]
)
```

that it is not what I need.

What I need is the following output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => DAS
    [1] => 1111[DR-Helpfull-R]
    [2] => RUN
    [3] => 
    [4] => [121668688374]
    [5] => N
    [6] => [+helpfull_+string]
)
```

Can someone please suggest a nice and elegant way to explode this string in the way I need it ?

what I forgot to mention, is that the string can have more or less groups. Examples:

```
DAS-1111[DR-Helpfull-R]-RUN--[121668688374]-N-[+helpfull_+string]
DAS-1111[DR-Helpfull-R]-RUN--[121668688374]
DAS-1111[DR-Helpfull-R]-RUN--[121668688374]-N-[+helpfull_+string]-anotherPart
```

**Update 1**

As mentioned by @axiac, the `preg_split` can do the work. But can you please help with the regex now ?

I have try this but it seems that it is incorrect:

`(?!\]\-)\-`

Comment: It looks like a job for [`preg_split()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php).

Comment: Is the string made of fixed length groups? Thus, will the first column (DAS in your example) always be first three characters? Will the second 18 characters etc?

Comment: @axiac Mmm I didn't knew this function. I am going to try and coming back again :)

Comment: @fiprojects Unfortunatelly not :( The length of each part can vary as well.

Comment: What determines the delimiter between 1st, 2nd and 3rd groups? Is the gap between 1st and 2nd a '-' character ? Is the gap between 2nd and 3rd a '-' that is outside square brackets? How have you determine the format? Your question needs to clarify this better otherwise folk here will just be pulling at straws.

Comment: @fiprojects Yes. Each group is delimitered by `-`. But the `-` should be outside the brakets

Comment: Hmm... it's not that easy with `preg_split()` but it works like a charm with [`preg_match_all()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php).

Comment: @axiac what is the regex you used ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code:

```
$str = 'DAS-1111[DR-Helpfull-R]-RUN--[121668688374]-N-[+helpfull_+string]';
$re  = '/([^-[]*(?:\[[^\]]*\])?[^-]*)-?/';

$matches = array();
preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
print_r($matches[1]);
```

Its output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => DAS
    [1] => 1111[DR-Helpfull-R]
    [2] => RUN
    [3] =>
    [4] => [121668688374]
    [5] => N
    [6] => [+helpfull_+string]
    [7] =>
)
```

There is an extra empty value at position `7` in the output. It appears because of the zero-or-one repetitions quantifier (`?`) placed at the end of the `regex`. The quantifier is needed because without it the last piece (at index `6`) is not matched.

You can remove the `?` after the last `-` and ask this way the dash (`-`) always match. In this case you must append an extra `-` to your input string.

**The regex**

```
(              # start of the 1st subpattern
               # the captured value is returned in $matches[1]
  [^-[]*       # match any character but '-' and '[', zero or more times
  (?:          # start of a non-capturing subpattern
    \[         # match an opening square bracket ('[')
    [^\]]*     # match any character but ']', zero or more times
    \]         # match a closing square bracket (']')
  )?           # end of the subpattern; it is optional (can appear 0 or 1 times)
  [^-]*        # match any character but '-', zero or more times
)              # end of the 1st subpattern
-?             # match an optional dash ('-')
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of exploding you should try to match the following pattern:

```
(?:^|-)([^-\[]*(?:\[[^\]]+\])?)
```

[Here is an example](https://regex101.com/r/kW8hB2/4):

```
$regex = '/(?:^|-)([^-\[]*(?:\[[^\]]+\])?)/';
$tests = array(
    'DAS-1111[DR-Helpfull-R]-RUN--[121668688374]-N-[+helpfull_+string]',
    'DAS-1111[DR-Helpfull-R]-RUN--[121668688374]',
    'DAS-1111[DR-Helpfull-R]-RUN--[121668688374]-N-[+helpfull_+string]-anotherPart'
);
foreach ($tests as $test) {
    preg_match_all($regex, $test, $result);
    print_r($result[1]);
}
```

Output:

```
// DAS-1111[DR-Helpfull-R]-RUN--[121668688374]-N-[+helpfull_+string]
Array
(
    [0] => DAS
    [1] => 1111[DR-Helpfull-R]
    [2] => RUN
    [3] => 
    [4] => [121668688374]
    [5] => N
    [6] => [+helpfull_+string]
)

// DAS-1111[DR-Helpfull-R]-RUN--[121668688374]
Array
(
    [0] => DAS
    [1] => 1111[DR-Helpfull-R]
    [2] => RUN
    [3] => 
    [4] => [121668688374]
)

// DAS-1111[DR-Helpfull-R]-RUN--[121668688374]-N-[+helpfull_+string]-anotherPart
Array
(
    [0] => DAS
    [1] => 1111[DR-Helpfull-R]
    [2] => RUN
    [3] => 
    [4] => [121668688374]
    [5] => N
    [6] => [+helpfull_+string]
    [7] => anotherPart
)
```

Comment: I used your pattern using both `preg_match` and `preg_split` but none works :(. Anyway, thank you for your try :)

Comment: @MerianosNikos my PHP is a bit rusty. I'll revise answer after some more testing.

Answer (score 1):

This case is perfect for the `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)` method.  You want to split your string on the hyphens, so long as they aren't inside of square brackets.

Easy. Just disqualify these hyphens as delimiters like so:

Pattern: `~\[[^]]+\](*SKIP)(*FAIL)|-~` ([Pattern Demo](https://regex101.com/r/s4DFdS/1))

Code: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/734a1a04a7dd94554460bf0b244e2c2a1d396714))

```
$strings=['DAS-1111[DR-Helpfull-R]-RUN--[121668688374]-N-[+helpfull_+string]',
          'DAS-1111[DR-Helpfull-R]-RUN--[121668688374]',
          'DAS-1111[DR-Helpfull-R]-RUN--[121668688374]-N-[+helpfull_+string]-anotherPart'];

foreach($strings as $string){
    var_export(preg_split('~\[[^]]+\](*SKIP)(*FAIL)|-~',$string));
    echo "\n\n";
}
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 'DAS',
  1 => '1111[DR-Helpfull-R]',
  2 => 'RUN',
  3 => '',
  4 => '[121668688374]',
  5 => 'N',
  6 => '[+helpfull_+string]',
)

array (
  0 => 'DAS',
  1 => '1111[DR-Helpfull-R]',
  2 => 'RUN',
  3 => '',
  4 => '[121668688374]',
)

array (
  0 => 'DAS',
  1 => '1111[DR-Helpfull-R]',
  2 => 'RUN',
  3 => '',
  4 => '[121668688374]',
  5 => 'N',
  6 => '[+helpfull_+string]',
  7 => 'anotherPart',
)
```